# Создание объекта класса для проверки параметра

Tags: java

Если в цикле сделать создание объектов в 1 переменную, старые классы удалятся из памяти, или так и будут висеть без ссылок на себя до скончания лет? 
Пример кода: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Да, память очиститься. Нашел упоминание о "Сборщике мусора", который убирает объекты их памяти если на них не ведут ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

В HotSpot для определения можно ли удалять объект сборщиком мусора применяется не подсчет ссылок на этот объект (который намного быстрее, но не обнаруживает "изолированные" группы объектов, которые имеют ссылку друг на друга), а проверка доступности объекта их корневых объектов (например, из main основного потока). 
Речь, конечно, идет "нормальных" сборщиках мусора, а не об экзотике типа Epsilon